# Swapping panes in tmux depends on active window

Tags: tmux

I am running `tmux` on a RHEL 8.6 server.  I ssh into the server from an OSX 13.6 Mac running `Iterm2-3.4.20`.

Here is my `~/.tmux.conf`

```
$ cat ~/.tmux.conf
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set -g history-limit 5000
#set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
setw -g mode-keys vi
set-option -g allow-rename off
```

After logging in, I attach to my `tmux` window. It has 3 `tmux` panes. If I'm on pane 0, I can swap panes 0 and 1 (i.e. `:swap-pane -s1 -t0`).  If I'm on pane 1, the **exact** same command does **not** switch.  Also, from pane 1 `:swap-pane -s0 -t1` does **not** work either.

From the `tmux` man page

> "target-pane (or src-pane or dst-pane) may be a pane ID" (edited) "

These commands should work.  I tried it from OSX's Terminal.app and observed the same behavior.  It seems that swapping panes is dependent on which pane is active should make a difference.

QUESTION :

1. How do I swap panes 0 and 1 when the active pane is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect when you are talking about "pane 0" and "pane 1" you are actually meaning "window 0" (window with index 0) and "window 1" (window with index 1) so you can use `swap-window`:

```
swap-window -s :0 -t :1
```

And "window id" is not the same thing as "window index". "Window id" is a string like `@1` which does not change for the lifetime of the window but "window index" is a relative number which may change when you create/kill/move windows. This also applies for panes.

This is from `man tmux`:

> Sessions, window and panes are each numbered with a **unique ID**; session IDs are prefixed with  a  `$`,  windows
> with  a  `@`, and panes with a `%`.  These are unique and are **unchanged** for the life of the session, window or
> pane in the tmux server.

Comment: I don't think so.  If I open a fresh shell and run `tmux`, that starts a new session.  If I then do `ctl-a (my cmd key) c`, it creates a new 'pane'.  If I do `ctl-a c`, that would create a third 'pane'.  This is the situation above.  Now I'd have 3 panes within one window.  Isn't this the correct terminology?

Comment: just try `swap-window -s :0 -t :1` and see if it does what u want.

Comment: here's a screenshot for "one window with 3 panes": https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRbaa.png

Comment: from `man tmux`: "Each **session** has one or more **windows** linked to it.  A **window** occupies the entire screen and may be split into rectangular **panes**, ..."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I guess I had jargon of windows and panes confused.  When I do `<prefix> x` on a `tmux` window (using the correct jargon now), it prompts `kill-pane 0? (y/n)`.  Although if my window has only one 'pane', this makes sense.  I bet this is where I got my terminology confused.